# How to add new file descriptors under /dev/fd?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, io, file-descriptor

I am using a remote linux server via ssh, so I don't have the super user authority. However, the mounted file descriptors in `/dev/fd` is not enough:

```
user >ls /dev/fd/
0  1  2
```

or:

```
user >ls /proc/self/fd
0  1  2
```

And what I want to is add new file descriptors, so that I can redirect the output stream in this way:

```
user >./main.exe 1>1.txt 2>2.txt 3>3.txt ...
```

Since the file descriptor is not enough, I can't create a file descriptor such as `/dev/fd/3`, an error triggered:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dev/fd/3'
```

Comment: Also see [Use multiple output stream in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48734950/608639) You should avoid accepting an answer until your question is actually answered. Please don't ask the same question multiple times in different ways.

Comment: @jww Actually, That question is from me...And I got an error when I am trying to use `open('/dev/fd/3', 'w')`

Comment: @jww The first question in about create a `fd` in python, this one more about linux I guess. Anyhow, thanks reminder

Comment: `/dev/fd` is a symlink to `/proc/self/fd`, which is just introspection of the file handles your program has open. You open a file handle, you get a new entry in that directory. `exec 3>somefile.txt` in shell will thus create a `/dev/fd/3`, because it opened `somefile.txt` and then used `dup2()` to renumber whatever automatically-assigned descriptor number it was given over to 3.

Answer (score 4):

`/dev/fd` is not a real directory. You don't add files to it, it just shows which fds the process (`ls` in your case) has open.

To open new FDs from the shell, you can just run

```
./yourprogram 3>myfile
```

If the program writes to FD 3, the output will end up in `myfile`.

Here's an example:

```
$ cat foo.c
#include <unistd.h>

void main() {
  write(3, "hello world\n", 12);
}

$ gcc foo.c -o foo

$ ./foo 3> myfile

$ cat myfile
hello world
```

Comment: Hi, firstly, I got an error while compiling: `error: 'write' was not declared in this scope`, then, if there a way to create file descriptor in python? I tried `open('/dev/fd/3', 'w')`, but got an error `IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dev/fd/3'`

Comment: @springcc, any time you call `open()`, that *always* assigns a file descriptor automatically. See the `fileno` attribute of your file objects in Python -- whatever number your file object has a `fileno` is also usable in `/dev/fd` by the same process.

Comment: @springcc, ...if for some odd reason you want to assign a *specific* number in Python, you can do that the same way the shell does it under-the-hood, with [`dup2()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.dup2).

Comment: @springcc, ...note the *by the same process* mentioned above -- if you run `./main.exe 3>3.txt`, that means that your `main.exe` has a `/dev/fd/3` it can open; it doesn't mean that the shell that started `main.exe` sees the same thing, because file descriptors are per-process. But you shouldn't be writing software in non-shell languages that depends on `/dev/fd` without a very compelling reason to -- it makes your code Linux-only, and generally for no purpose.

Comment: Only problem I get compiling `foo.c` is a warning that `main()` should return an `int` not a `void`.  @springcc probably missed the `#include <unistd.h>`.